# how can i convert or print big html table into pdf using jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a big table that i want to **either print or convert to pdf**.

**The problem now most of the columns are left for the print**.

I don't know why `columns` are `left` for the **print** .

**Please refer (below snippet is not working) Jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/85okepx8/12/

**Here is demo:**

```js
$('#print').click(function(){
   $('#examples').printThis();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/printThis/1.12.2/printThis.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" id="print">Print</a>

<table class="table table-boardered" id="examples">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>

            <th>Customer Name</th>

            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Order Number</th>

            <th>PO Number</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
            <th>Billing Address</th>
            <th>Shipping Address</th>
            <th>Installing Address</th>
            <th>Design</th>
            <th>Production</th>
            <th>Shipping</th>
            <th>Install</th>
            <th>Production Manager</th>
            <th>Project manager</th>
            <th>Sales Representatives</th>
            <th>Shipping Method</th>

            <th>Created At</th>

            <th>Status</th>
            <td style="display:none;"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr>

            <td>lNsbTEo</td>
            <td>eweeedm</td>
            <td>fdvjhdhd</td>
            <td>1958</td>
            <td>445</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2018/01/27 17:03</td>
            <td>fnhbbhf</td>
            <td>shipping address by me</td>
            <td>installing address</td>
            <td>design</td>
            <td>production</td>
            <td>shipping</td>
            <td>install</td>
            <td>production manager</td>
            <td>project manager</td>
            <td>kfgkk</td>
            <td>shipping method</td>

            <td style="color:#0277bd">16-01-2018</td>

            <td class="statusNotClass">
                Completed
            </td>

            <td>
            </td>

        </tr>
        
        
        <!-- second row -->
        
          <tr>

            <td>lNsbTEo</td>
            <td>eweeedm</td>
            <td>fdvjhdhd</td>
            <td>1958</td>
            <td>445</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2018/01/27 17:03</td>
            <td>fnhbbhf</td>
            <td>shipping address by me</td>
            <td>installing address</td>
            <td>design</td>
            <td>production</td>
            <td>shipping</td>
            <td>install</td>
            <td>production manager</td>
            <td>project manager</td>
            <td>kfgkk</td>
            <td>shipping method</td>

            <td style="color:#0277bd">16-01-2018</td>

            <td class="statusNotClass">
                Completed
            </td>

            <td>
            </td>

        </tr>
        
        <!-- end of second row -->

    </tbody>

</table>
```

The intention of doing this is to have a final copy of my customer related data, to have a good insight into the customer data.

Please help me thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Works for me on Chrome, but the text is tiny, of course..

Comment: print just print the data on screen. And you have scroll in your data. So columns are left in the screen when you click on print button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here All coulmns are Showing !

```js
function printContent(el) {
        var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
        var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" id="print" onclick="printContent('examples')">Print</a>
<div class="container" id="examples">
<table class="table table-dark">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>

            <th>Customer Name</th>

            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Order Number</th>

            <th>PO Number</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
            <th>Billing Address</th>
            <th>Shipping Address</th>
            <th>Installing Address</th>
            <th>Design</th>
            <th>Production</th>
            <th>Shipping</th>
            <th>Install</th>
            <th>Production Manager</th>
            <th>Project manager</th>
            <th>Sales Representatives</th>
            <th>Shipping Method</th>

            <th>Created At</th>

            <th>Status</th>
            <td style="display:none;"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr>

            <td>lNsbTEo</td>
            <td>eweeedm</td>
            <td>fdvjhdhd</td>
            <td>1958</td>
            <td>445</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2018/01/27 17:03</td>
            <td>fnhbbhf</td>
            <td>shipping address by me</td>
            <td>installing address</td>
            <td>design</td>
            <td>production</td>
            <td>shipping</td>
            <td>install</td>
            <td>production manager</td>
            <td>project manager</td>
            <td>kfgkk</td>
            <td>shipping method</td>

            <td style="color:#0277bd">16-01-2018</td>

            <td class="statusNotClass">
                Completed
            </td>

            <td>
            </td>

        </tr>
        
        
        <!-- second row -->
        
          <tr>

            <td>lNsbTEo</td>
            <td>eweeedm</td>
            <td>fdvjhdhd</td>
            <td>1958</td>
            <td>445</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2018/01/27 17:03</td>
            <td>fnhbbhf</td>
            <td>shipping address by me</td>
            <td>installing address</td>
            <td>design</td>
            <td>production</td>
            <td>shipping</td>
            <td>install</td>
            <td>production manager</td>
            <td>project manager</td>
            <td>kfgkk</td>
            <td>shipping method</td>

            <td style="color:#0277bd">16-01-2018</td>

            <td class="statusNotClass">
                Completed
            </td>

            <td>
            </td>

        </tr>
        
        <!-- end of second row -->

    </tbody>

</table>
</div>
```